# Shorten URLs within CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes

This question has been asked a few times but I can't seem to find a solution that helps me which is why I am trying here.

I have my site setup with the following for URLs I am using CodeIgniter I have a controller called user which loads a user view.

So my URLs are structured as follows:

http://example.com/user/#/username

I want to try and strip out the user controller from the URL to tidy up my URL so they would just read:

http://example.com/#/username

Is this possible I have been looking at route and have tried lots of different options but none have worked?

```
$route['/'] = "user";
```

Could anyone offer any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the '*#*' in your URLs is a valid function and '*username*' is a parameter for that function, then this [route](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) should work:

```
$route['#/(:any)'] = "user/#/$1";
```

Depending on what usernames are to be routed you may want to change the wildcard. For example, if you only wanted to route numbers as the parameter, you could change `(:any)` to `(:num)`.

> (:num) will match a segment containing only numbers.
>
> (:any) will match a segment containing any character.

You can also use regular expressions to define [routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) rules, allowing you to further restrict what is routed.

Comment: Hi Lefters thanks for the reply if i run that i get the error Message: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '/' any reason why it maybe giving me that error

Comment: sorry and also the hash is because i am using sammy.js

Comment: No worries. Is the 'username' in the URL a parameter to the `index` function in the `user` controller?

Comment: Hi Lefters no the username param in the url is being called by sammy.js through javascript not php. Thanks for the help